# Аватар на почтовый ящик. VPS, Ubuntu 16, Vesta

Tags: ubuntu, email, vps, vds, vesta

Можно ли установить аватар на почтовый ящик, созданный на своем VPS, если из панели управления(у меня Vesta), нет такого готового функционала? Возможно можно подключиться через терминал к серверу и выполнить тонкую настройку? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не имеет никакого отношения к vps. Для mail.ru это ставится в настройках на https://postmaster.mail.ru, для Яндекса вроде бы нужно загрузить аватарку для нужной почты на Gravatar

Comment: @andreymal Ок, а что для gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не имеет никакого отношения к vps. Для mail.ru это ставится в настройках на postmaster.mail.ru, для Яндекса вроде бы нужно загрузить аватарку для нужной почты на Gravatar – Спасибо andreymal